# How to deploy AWS CLI within a project so I can use it programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an existing web application and I want to add S3 functionality to it. I have the aws cli working on my local machine. I can upload files to S3 on the command line.

However, I am having trouble finding documentation about how to encapsulate this and put it into my project repo so I can use it programmatically. For example, I assume I need to add some sort of config file to the project. What about the aws executable? Those sorts of things.

It's a Symfony project (PHP).

Comment: Which language are you building your app in?

Comment: @TomHarvey edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS provides variety of **SDKs** to work with its services:

- [Tools to Build on AWS: Tools for developing and managing applications on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/)

Depending on your **programming language**, you usually use the SDK you require, e.g. in Python or Node.js, in your project. The SDK is also available for [PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/).

The configuration aspects depend on where your application is going to be hosted. If it runs on AWS infrastructure,  you usually use **IAM roles** (e.g. [instance roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)) to provide needed permissions (e.g. to read and write to S3). If it is outside of AWS, you can also use roles through, e.g. [web federation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html).